# How crop image in android

Tags: android

I want to use this method for crop image in android

And I found the code on the page

But there is a problem

I did not know how to get the picUri

```
private void performCrop(Uri picUri) {
        try {
            Intent cropIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
            cropIntent.putExtra("crop", true);
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 128);
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 128);
            cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
            startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);
        }
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
            String errorMessage = "Whoops - your device doesn't support the crop action!";
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PIC_CROP) {
            if (data != null) {
                // get the returned data
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                // get the cropped bitmap
                Bitmap selectedBitmap = extras.getParcelable("data");

                img.setImageBitmap(selectedBitmap);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it:
What the method below does is taking a bitmap and returns a uri.

```
public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

So this is what your code will look like:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PIC_CROP) {
        if (data != null) {
            // get the returned data
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            // get the cropped bitmap
            Bitmap selectedBitmap = extras.getParcelable("data");
            //get the Uri when it is returned from the function.
            picUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), selectedBitmap);
            img.setImageBitmap(selectedBitmap);
        }
    }
}
public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

This should be how you get the Uri from a bitmap. Hope it works!

Comment: what is inImage?

Comment: Mistake I use from Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

Comment: Try getting the Uri through the method that I gave you above. That will work. Once you get the bitmap from the intent, you can pass it in to the method to get the Uri.